# Internet Service в Activity

Tags: android

В Service делаю интернет запрос, для получения переменной ASD.

В MainActivity использую переменную ASD из Service.

Как в MainActivity подождать пока Service не получит переменную ASD.

По времени это займет где - то 3-8 сек...

Код большой сюда не влезет, вместо кода описал теорией

Вот код http://pastebin.com/pMzSKTXY

Там все объяснил, Но если надо могу файлы выслать но они большие

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "подождать"? Заморозка интерфейса или просто реакция на завершение запроса с сервисе? Если второе, то можно LocalBroadcastManager использовать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, заморозка MainActivity Но так чтобы на Service это не повлияло.

Чтобы разморозка произошла тогда когда Service получит переменную ASD. так как в данный момент при запуске она равна null. Спустя 1-10 сек. она получит какие тоданные

Comment: Может я чего не понимаю, но мне кажется товарищу @xTIGRx нужно, что бы интерфейс всего навсего не реагировал во время запроса.

Comment: @katso, вот и мне так кажется. Но не может же быть всё так просто... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к сервис работает в основном потоке по умолчанию, то сделайте в сервисе метод, возвращающий вашу переменную.
В этом методе усыпите поток `Thread.sleep()` сразу после начала запроса в сеть.
После окончания запроса в сеть разбудите поток и верните переменную.
Будьте готовы к падению приложения при остановке потока основного более чем на 5 сек. и подумайте о том, чтобы сделать всё как-то иначе.

Comment: А иначе как можно? а то я думаю что я какой - то гавнокод сделал...

Comment: Не хватает информации для дачи ответа. Может вам коммент @katso поможет?..\

Comment: Я ссылку на код выслал сюда, для более точного ответа. Мне реально помощь нужна, чтобы в дальнейшем таких вещей не делать...

Comment: Мне код (тем более большой) смотреть не досуг. Чем вас предложение отключить кнопки не устраивает?..